# Communicating with Arduino and Python via CmdMessenger, not working

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I implement a simply CmdMessenger example to permits Arduino communicate with PC via serial port.

The program intent to listen to serial waiting for the command '0;'. When this command is typed, Arduino reads a temperature sensor and write temperature result to serial.

It work's fine from serial monitor, but I cannot use it with PYthon using pySerial. I think I'm doing something wrong in python implementation, below is the code snippet:
EDiTED: the code below runs as expected if I run in debug mode (on PyCharm). I put a breakpoint at beggining on this line:

```
    if (not self.serialConnection.isOpen()): ...
```

and run with 'Resume Program' from there and it works. I don't know why it don't run in 'Normal Mode'.

```
import serial
import time

class Temperature:
    def __init__(self, comPath='/dev/ttyACM0', bauds=115200):
        self.serialConnection = serial.Serial(comPath, bauds, parity=serial.PARITY_ODD, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
                                              bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS)

    def queryTemperature(self):
        if (not self.serialConnection.isOpen()):
            self.serialConnection.open()

        # prints True:
        print self.serialConnection.isOpen()
        self.serialConnection.write("0;\n")
        time.sleep(2)
        while self.serialConnection.inWaiting() == 0:
            pass
        # don't reach this point. It stops on loop above
        time.sleep(2)
        iw = self.serialConnection.inWaiting()
        temp = (self.serialConnection.read(iw))
        self.serialConnection.close()
        return temp
```

and the call of the method queryTemperature:

```
from temp_read import *
dObject = Temperature('COM3')
print dObject.queryTemperature();
```

the program doesn't finish. It seems that it stops on the loop:

```
        while self.serialConnection.inWaiting() == 0:
            pass
```

bellow is the arduino sketch:

```
#include <CmdMessenger.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

int pinTemp = 13;

CmdMessenger cmdMessenger = CmdMessenger (Serial);
OneWire oneWire (pinTemp);
DallasTemperature sensors (&oneWire);


enum {
  kReadTemperature,  
  kStatus,
};

void attachCommandCallbacks (){
  cmdMessenger.attach (onUnknownCommand);
  cmdMessenger.attach (kReadTemperature, onReadTemperature);  
}

void onStatus (){
  Serial.println ("status");

}

void onUnknownCommand (){
  Serial.println ("unknow");
}

void onReadTemperature (){
  Serial.println ("readTemp");
  sensors.requestTemperatures();
  delay (1500);
  float temp = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);        
  cmdMessenger.sendCmd(kStatus, (float) temp);

}

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(115200); 
 sensors.begin ();
cmdMessenger.printLfCr(); 
  attachCommandCallbacks();


}

void loop() {
  cmdMessenger.feedinSerialData();


}
```

Comment: ive found inWaiting to be somewhat unreliable ... maybe add a sleep instead of a pass .... or read until you get some character that indicates end of message... ive also found with arduino it helps to sleep for several seconds after opening the serial connection ....

Comment: this code doesn't print anything too: time.sleep(3)
        r = self.serialConnection.readline()
        print r

Comment: you shouldnt need  bytes in py2 as just strings suffice ... try "\n" instead of "\r" for your newline ... try just reading single bytes instead of lines ... if all else fails you can always try printing your cmd right before you send it, and/or setting up free serial port monitor  to watch your serial port communication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not using your code, but to achieve the same functionality, I have written a robust python interface to CmdMessenger (https://github.com/harmsm/PyCmdMessenger).  You could use it to do this task by:

```
import PyCmdMessenger

# set up serial connection at proper baud rate
a = PyCmdMessenger.ArduinoBoard('/dev/ttyACM0',baud_rate=115200)

# list of commands at top of sketch, with argument formats
commands = [["kReadTemperature","f"],
            ["kSendTemperature","f"],
            ["kStatus","s"]]

cmd = PyCmdMessenger.CmdMessenger(a,commands)
cmd.send("kReadTemperature")
print(cmd.receive())
```

The changes to your arduino sketch would be adding `kSendTemperature` to your initial command enumeration:

```
enum {
      kReadTemperature,  
      kSendTemperature,
      kStatus,
};
```

replacing your send command so it sends the float as a binary string:

```
//cmdMessenger.sendCmd(kStatus, (float) temp);
cmdMessenger.sendBinCmd(kSendTemperature, (float) temp);
```

and removing the extra `Serial.Println(XXX)` commands.